# Perl regex: matching the first instance of a string after a given match

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to parse a text file using perl regular expressions. Here's an example data set:

```
"Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5"
"val1-1", "\\path\to\val1-2.txt", "val1-3", "\\path\to\val1-4.ini", "val1-5.txt"
"val2-1", "val2-2", "\\path\to\val2-3.txt", "\\path\to\val2-4.ini", "val2-5.txt"
"\\path\to\val3-1.txt", "val3-2", "val3-3", "\\path\to\val3-4.ini", "val3-5.txt"
```

For each line of text, I'm trying to match the first instance of .txt file name; the bolded substrings in the above data set.

I thought this would work:

```
while(<INFILE>) {
    if(m/\\(.*?\.txt)"/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
\path\to\val1-2.txt
\path\to\val2-3.txt
\path\to\val3-1.txt
```

but it doesn't because it will match the complete path, not just the filename.

Now this works:

```
while(<INFILE>) {
    if(my @matches = $_ =~ m/(.*?)"/g) {
        foreach (@matches) {
            print "$1\n" if(m/.*\\(.*?\.txt)/);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
val1-2.txt
val2-3.txt
val3-1.txt
```

But I would suppose there must be a way to do this with a single match expression?

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
my $re = qr~\\([^\\"]+)"~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    if(my @m = /$re/g) {
        say "@m";
    }
}

__DATA__
"Field1", "Field2", "Field3", "Field4", "Field5"
"val1-1", "\\path\to\val1-2.txt", "val1-3", "\\path\to\val1-4.ini", "val1-5.txt"
"val2-1", "val2-2", "\\path\to\val2-3.txt", "\\path\to\val2-4.ini", "val2-5.txt"
"\\path\to\val3-1.txt", "val3-2", "val3-3", "\\path\to\val3-4.ini", "val3-5.txt"
```

**output:**

```
val1-2.txt val1-4.ini
val2-3.txt val2-4.ini
val3-1.txt val3-4.ini
```

If you only want the first .txt, do:

```
my $re = qr~\\([^\\"]+\.txt)~;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    /$re/ && say $1;
}
```

Comment: OP said he wants the first `.txt`, so no need for the `.ini` I guess. The quoted regex is a good idea though. :)

Comment: @simbabque is correct: no need for .ini. Here's how I translated your regex just in case this helps someone else also: `[^\\"]` ==> match anything that is NOT \ or ". `+` ==> match at least once. So `[^\\"]+\.txt` becomes: match any string separated by characters \ or " and whose length is at least one character and ends with .txt.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
while (<DATA>) {
    if(m/([^\\]+\.txt)"/) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}

__END__
val1-2.txt
val2-3.txt
val3-1.txt
```

You don't need the  `\` outside your capture group. Instead, look for everything that's not a backslash instead of just everything. Since you want the file to have a name in front of the `.txt` you want the `+` quantifier, not the `*?` which is *match something or nothing but get as few as possible*.